# How to fix this elimination on successive node appearance using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this input file:

```
<myroot>
    <list id="xxx">
        <node id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>                
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>  

            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>  
                 <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                 <item1 id="a0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                
        </node>
    </list>
</myroot>
```

And my output:

```
 <myroot>
        <list id="xxx">
            <node id="a">
                <section id="i">
                    <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                        <somechild>a</somechild>
                    </item1>
                    <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>                
                </section>  

                <section id="i" />
            </node>
        </list>
    </myroot>

**While the expected output should be:**

<myroot>
    <list id="xxx">
        <node id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>                
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>  

            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>  
                 <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                
        </node>
    </list>
</myroot>
```

XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="first-in-group" as="element()*">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="concat(node-name(.), '|', @id,'|', @method)">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="concat(@id, '|', @method)">
                        <xsl:sequence 
              select="for $pos in 1 to count(current-group())
                      return current-group()[$pos]
                              [every $item 
                              in subsequence(current-group(), 1, $pos - 1) 
                              satisfies not(deep-equal($item, current-group()[$pos]))] "/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="first-in-group" select="$first-in-group" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*">
        <xsl:param name="first-in-group" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test="$first-in-group intersect .">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another scenario:

```
<myroot>
    <list id="xxx">
        <node id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>  

            <section id="i">               
                <item1 id="a1" method="start"> 
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous, because the previous node has id of 'a1', so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="a0" method="start"> <!-- this one is successive from the previous so we eliminate -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                
        </node>
    </list>
</myroot>
```

Expected Output:

```
<myroot>
    <list id="xxx">
        <node id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="a0" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>  

            <section id="i">               
                <item1 id="a1" method="start">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
            </section>                
        </node>
    </list>
</myroot>
```

The idea is to remove successive node with the same method. In the example :

- start/start/stop/start/start --> start/stop/start

The XSLT can remove successive node but not working for the scenario above.

Can anyone point me to where should I change the xslt to accomodate above scenario? Really appreciate for the help.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you're over complicating it. You should be able to match/strip any element that is equal to the first preceding element of the same name.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*][deep-equal(.,preceding::*[name()=current()/name()][1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (using your updated xml above)

```
<myroot>
   <list id="xxx">
      <node id="a">
         <section id="i">
            <item1 id="a0" method="start">
               <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>
            <item1 id="a0" method="start">
               <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
         </section>
         <section id="i">
            <item1 id="a0" method="stop"/>
            <item1 id="a0" method="start">
               <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
         </section>
      </node>
   </list>
</myroot>
```

Comment: fixed issue of dropped `<somechild>`

Comment: Hi, It turns out that the removal only works on the first `<section>` part only. Do you have any suggestion to make your solution works on the second `<section>`. Please see my extended input update. Thanks very much.

Comment: @John - I'm not sure what you mean. Using your extended input I get exactly what you have listed under `While the expected output should be:`. If the expected output is different than what's in your question, please update it.

Comment: @John - Also, if I take your extended input and manually delete the items that you have marked that should be removed, that also matches the output I get with the stylesheet in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong one.  I have added other scenario, So basically the successive will consider `same element name, same id and same method`. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: No worries I think I have found the answer by changing it to `<xsl:template match="*[*][deep-equal(.,preceding::*[name()=current()/name()][@id=current()/@id][1])]"/>`. Thanks anyway..